# The "backoff" option does not exist error after upgrade into laravel version 10 and php version 8.1.16

Tags: laravel, queue

```
            The "backoff" option does not exist.
            This error coming after laravel version upgrade. 
            I have below signature in workcommand class which will run when queue is getting 
            processed
           <?php
```

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository as Cache;

/**

- CLI command
- php artisan news:work
- 
- @package App\Console\Commands
  */
  class NewsWork extends \Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand
  {
  /**

  - The name and signature of the console command.
  - 
  - @var string
    */
    protected $signature = 'news:work
    {connection? : The name of the queue connection to work}
    {--name=default : The name of the worker}
    {--queue= : The names of the queues to work}
    {--daemon : Run the worker in daemon mode (Deprecated)}
    {--once : Only process the next job on the queue}
    {--stop-when-empty : Stop when the queue is empty}
    {--backoff= 0: The number of seconds to wait before retrying a job that encountered an
    uncaught exception}
    {--delay=0 : The number of seconds to delay failed jobs (Deprecated)}
    {--max-jobs=0 : The number of jobs to process before stopping}
    {--max-time=0 : The maximum number of seconds the worker should run}
    {--force : Force the worker to run even in maintenance mode}
    {--memory=128 : The memory limit in megabytes}
    {--sleep=3 : Number of seconds to sleep when no job is available}
    {--rest=0 : Number of seconds to rest between jobs}
    {--timeout=60 : The number of seconds a child process can run}
    {--tries=1 : Number of times to attempt a job before logging it failed}';

  /**

  - The console command description.
  - 
  - @var string
    */
    protected $description = 'Start processing news jobs on the queue as a daemon';

  /**

  - Create a new queue work command.
  - 
  - @param  \App\Jobs\NewsWorker $worker
  - @return void
    */
    public function __construct(\App\Jobs\NewsWorker $worker)
    {
    parent::__construct($worker, app(Cache::class));
    }
    }